# Exception not raised - Python

Tags: python, exception

```
class client():
    def __init__(self,identitate,nume,cnp,filme_inchiriate,inchirieri):
        self.__identitate=identitate
        self.__nume=nume
        self.__cnp=cnp
        self.__filme_inchiriate=filme_inchiriate
        self.__inchirieri=inchirieri  

    def get_identitate(self):
        return self.__identitate


    def get_nume(self):
        return self.__nume


    def get_cnp(self):
        return self.__cnp

    def get_filme_inchiriate(self):
        return self.__filme_inchiriate


    def get_inchirieri(self):
        return self.__inchirieri


    def set_identitate(self, value):
        self.__identitate = value


    def set_nume(self, value):
        self.__nume = value


    def set_cnp(self, value):
        self.__cnp = value


    def set_filme_inchiriate(self, value):
        self.__filme_inchiriate = value


    def set_inchirieri(self, value):
        self.__inchirieri = value


    def del_identitate(self):
        del self.__identitate


    def del_nume(self):
        del self.__nume


    def del_cnp(self):
        del self.__cnp


    def del_filme_inchiriate(self):
        del self.__filme_inchiriate


    def del_inchirieri(self):
        del self.__inchirieri

    identitate = property(get_identitate, set_identitate, del_identitate, "identitate's docstring")
    nume = property(get_nume, set_nume, del_nume, "nume's docstring")
    cnp = property(get_cnp, set_cnp, del_cnp, "cnp's docstring")
    filme_inchiriate = property(get_filme_inchiriate, set_filme_inchiriate, del_filme_inchiriate, "filme_inchiriate's docstring")
    inchirieri = property(get_inchirieri, set_inchirieri, del_inchirieri, "inchirieri's docstring")
    def __str__(self):
        return "ID: " + str(self.get_identitate()) + " Nume: " + str(self.get_nume()) + " CNP: "+ str(self.get_cnp())


from entities import *

class validator_client():

     def validate_client(self,client):
         erori=[]
         if client.get_identitate=="":
             erori.append("Nu ati introdus ID!")
         if client.get_nume=="":
             erori.append("Nu ati indorus nume!")
         if len(erori)>0:
             raise ValidatorException(erori)

     def haha(self,client):
         if client.get_identitate()=="1":
             print "hahahah" 

class ValidatorException(Exception):
     def __init__(self,erori):
         self.__erori=erori
     def get_erori(self):
         return self.__erori
     def __str__(self):
         return self.erori
     erori = property(get_erori, None, None, None)


client1=client("",2,3,4,5)
validare=validator_client()
try:
     validare.validate_client(client1)
except:
     ValidatorException
     print (ValidatorException)
```

`client()` is a class that has 5 attributes from which the first one is id, it has a getter and setter so there is no problem with the class but why is not printed any errors when I run this?

Comment: Your `except` clause does not catch a specific exception. You may want to read up on the [`try` compound statement documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) to see *how* you catch a specific exception.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Not enough sleep.  You're right.  I ignored the whole client constructor since the client class isn't shown.  D'oh!

Comment: I think there's a bit of a "Python isn't Java" problem going on here too.  The `validator_client` class seems to have no purpose other than bundling a few methods together; `validate_client()` and `haha()` probably make more sense here as just straight functions in the module.

Comment: I edited the question and put the client() class too, haha method from validator_client() was just a method used for tests

Comment: That's beside the point.  Python isn't Java.  There's no private or protected in Python, so writing piles of setter/getter methods that just set member attributes is not the way to go.  Functions are also first class objects in Python, and the module that owns them is an object itself once loaded, so there's no good reason (99% of the time at least) to wrap collections of methods in objects unless the object actually has some state information that differs across instances.

Comment: The pointless property are also bad. You're essentially adding 63 lines that do absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things: you aren't calling that getter, you are getting the method (unless it is a property, in which case, why is it called get).  Also, as @Martijn Pieters says in the comments, your except clause is catching all exceptions, then printing the string representation of the `ValidatorException` class, not the exception instance.

As far as the `except` clause, I think what you may be looking for is:

```
except ValidatorException as ve:
    print(ve)
```

Comment: As I said in the answer, the other part of the problem is that you aren't actually calling the getters in `validate_client()`.  You are just retrieving the method object attributes off the client object, which will never be equal to `""`.  You need `client.get_identitate()==""` and `client.get_nume()==""` instead.  Or better, don't use getters, use straight attributes or a properties.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Kituri\eclipse-jee-juno-SR1-win32\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_2.7.1.2012100913\pysrc\pydev_runfiles.py", line 432, in __get_module_from_str
    mod = __import__(modname)
  File "D:/Python/Laborator 5-7/domain\validator.py", line 35, in <module>
    print(ve)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type list)
ERROR: Module: validator could not be imported (file: D:\Python\Laborator 5-7\domain\validator.py).

Comment: It worked , thank you but now i seem to get an error from the compiler

Comment: Oops, that's yet another bug.  `__str__` in your exception class needs to return a string, so `return str(self.erori)` should fix your problem there.

Comment: I solve it i needed a str(self.erori) in the __str__ method thnaks again for your fast and good answer